# Centos 7 - Php56w - and some php module issues

Tags: php, linux, centos

We are setting up a server and it has a list of scripts and php modules which I just about have installed but there are a few things still giving issues.

We have Centos 7 and PHP56w installed

I need to install

```
extension=mailparse.so
extension=oauth.so
```

but am having issues.. 
php56w-common is installed but I can't seem to activate these extensions. When I try to yum install they give me  either does not exist or php56w-common conflicts with php54-commmon. but we don't have 5.4 installed? I am trying to figure out why it is pulling that version even when forcing a php56w install.

In order to install mailparse I have other dependencies that are needed like php-zend-abi and php-api ...

When you go to install anything they either do not exist, give dependency issues to things you can't install or give the 56w 54 conflict.

I had to use the webtatic repo for some scripts not in the remi or centos options but there is no php54 that I can find anywhere.

I ran - `rpm -qa | grep php`
and get this

```
php56w-tidy-5.6.17-1.w7.x86_64
php56w-mysqlnd-5.6.17-1.w7.x86_64
php56w-pear-1.10.1-1.w7.noarch
php56w-5.6.17-1.w7.x86_64
php56w-process-5.6.17-1.w7.x86_64
php56w-xml-5.6.17-1.w7.x86_64
php56w-pdo-5.6.17-1.w7.x86_64
php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el7.noarch
phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.2-1.el7.noarch
php56w-cli-5.6.17-1.w7.x86_64
php56w-devel-5.6.17-1.w7.x86_64
php56w-mbstring-5.6.17-1.w7.x86_64
php-php-gettext-1.0.11-12.el7.noarch
php56w-bcmath-5.6.17-1.w7.x86_64
php56w-gd-5.6.17-1.w7.x86_64
php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts-6.2.11-1.el7.noarch
php56w-common-5.6.17-1.w7.x86_64
```

Any ideas how I can get the mailparse and oauth modules enabled?

Comment: You will probably get a better answer from http://serverfault.com/

Comment: If there aren't `php56w-` prefixed packages for the extensions you want then webtatic doesn't package them and you can't use the default packages for them (because the version of php they are built for is wrong). So you probably get to build them yourself or find a repository that provides the version of php you want and the extensions you need.

Comment: >  had to use the webtatic repo for some scripts not in the remi  => obviously wrong, they are in "remi" ;) but not in webtatic.

Answer (score 0):

If some extensions are missing in your provider repository, probably you should consider another repository with more features.

Check extensions available in "remi-php56" repository on http://blog.remirepo.net/pages/PECL-extensions-RPM-status

Yes, both mailparse and oauth are there.

For configuration, see http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/